# How to save Scroll position on rotate in Fragment on ScrollView with other Fragment inside it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, uiscrollview

I have `FragmentA` with `ScrollView`. There are few items in `ScrollView`. One of middle items - is `FragmentB`. If I add `FragmentB` dynamically, scroll position lost on screen rotate.

Documentation (http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

says: "Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically." So all my tries to add `FragmentB` in layout file which `FragmentA` inflates case exceptions.